# Get interval between two words in a text and store in array

Tags: php

Im trying to store the interval between two words in a text inside a array.

Example:

Text:

```
66625sha:
content1content1
28sj123

66625sha:
content2content2
28sj123
```

Expect output:

```
array('content1content1','content2content2');
```

I tried:

```
$data = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$word1 = "66625sha:";
$word2 = "28sj123";

 preg_match('/'.preg_quote($word1).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($word2).'/is', $data, $match);
```

But it just store the first interval. I need to store all the intervals.
How can I do it?

Comment: did you try `preg_match_all`?

Comment: Lol , now its working

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP's has solved the issue and said about it